# Salerank of a sub category through Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-scraping

I am using Amazon product advertising API. I can get the model number and sale rank from the API by passing `ResponseGroup=Large%2CSalesRank`.

However it displays only the sale rank of the top category. For example A product has Amazon Best Sellers Rank #2 in Kitchen & Dining and 12,345 in Accessories. I can only get 12,345 as a sale rank.

How can I get the #2 in Kitchen & Dining Category value?

Comment: I tried direct scrapping from that page and that is very slow and I actually want to use API. I tried to use different ResponseGroup and I couldn't get what I want so only I posted it here

Comment: Did you find a solution ?